# Rails Cocoon alternate colors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

Is it possible to add alternating colors for new rows created by Cocoon gem?

https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cycle`

```
<tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even", name: "alt_rows")%>">
  ...
<tr>
<% reset_cycle("alt_rows") %>
```

then add an .odd and/or .even class to your css file.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle

Comment: it should do - i'm using it with cocoon.  can you post your code?